# Toxin Adaptations

Tags: creature-design, super-powers, genetic-engineering, body-modification

How could humans be modified to be immune to tetradotoxin, as well as be given the ability to secrete it, like a newt or pufferfish?

It appears to be possible at a minute level to be resistant to it:
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/10580103/
https://academic.oup.com/mbe/article/31/11/2836/2925679

Answer (score 6):

**Protection can be via immunity.**

Our bodies protect us from funky chemicals by producing antibodiies that stick to those funky chemicals so they are unable to do their funky things.  That works for tetrodotoxin.

[Prophylaxis and treatment with a monoclonal antibody of tetrodotoxin poisoning in mice](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8585093/)

> The ability of a tetrodotoxin (TTX)-specific monoclonal antibody to
> confer passive protection against lethal TTX challenge was
> investigated. The monoclonal antibody, T20G10, has an estimated
> affinity for TTX of approximately 10(-9) M.... Therapy studies
> simulating oral intoxication were performed with mice given a lethal
> dose of TTX.... Death occurred within 25-35 min in 6/6 mice not
> treated with T20G10. However, 500 micrograms T20G10 administered via
> the tail vein 10-15 min after oral TTX exposure prevented death in 6/6
> mice. Lower doses of mAb conferred less protection.

Your immune people have antibodies that inactivate tetrodotoxin. Easy peasy.

---

Metazoans do not synthesize tetrodotoxin.  **It is synthesized for them by symbotic bacteria.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrodotoxin#Sources_in_nature

> The association of bacterial species with the production of the toxin
> is unequivocal – Lago and coworkers state, "[e]ndocellular symbiotic
> bacteria have been proposed as a possible source of eukaryotic TTX by
> means of an exogenous pathway,"[2] and Chau and coworkers note that
> the "widespread occurrence of TTX in phylogenetically distinct
> organisms… strongly suggests that symbiotic bacteria play a role in
> TTX biosynthesis"

Humans have symbiotic bacteria that live in our greasy glands.  I suspect it might be easier to engineer one of our ancient bacterial friends to make tetrodotoxin than to persuade a human body that a bug like Aeromonas was a good symbiont to have in the mouth or sebaceous glands.  But maybe.  Just like the animals, your tetrodotoxin laden folks will have bacteria synthesize it where they live and then have it spread over the body.

For myself, I will have the bacteria in my sebaceous glands engineered to produce the great smell of Brut.